# class method error in c++

Tags: c++

I am getting an error when I declare a class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testing/test.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{    
    test links;
    string content="this is an string";
    links.getcont(content);
}
```

#### test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class test {    
  public:    
    string getcont(string content); 

};

#endif /* TEST_H_ */
```

#### test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    
string getcont(string content)    
{
    cout << content;
    return content;
}
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
undefined reference to test::getcont(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
```

Comment: That can't be the whole error message.  Oh, and what is `links.getlinks`?

Comment: I think you are missing some of the error.  That is just the type you are using.  Can you please add the full error message.

Comment: undefined reference to test::getcont(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
)

Comment: what is links ? An instance of  test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well , in your test.cpp file replace the `getcont` function for this

```
string test::getcont(string content){ //code here; }
```

The problem is that you are not saying that getcont is a member function of the test class.

Also, consider making it a const function and passing a const string reference

```
string
test::getcont( const string& content) const
{
    return content;
}
```